# How to find out which sub-domain has been indexed more in Google?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have some sub-domains. I use "site:example.com" in Google search input to find out the number of pages Google has indexed from my domain overall.

How can I find out which sub-domain has been indexed more? Can I do it for others domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `site:` [search operator](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en) to return the number of results for [subdomains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain) and URLs.

For example, if you use `site:voice.google.com` you'll see only a few hundred results (at the time of this post). Same with URLs like `site:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google` which returns roughly ten results.

For even more details on indexed URLs, you can add each subdomain as a site in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

Comment: but what if I don't know the sub-domain names ? for example if I want to check other company sub-domains indexed result ?

Comment: I don't know of a way to obtain a list of indexed subdomains for someone else's domain without first knowing them, other than using a script/tool to query Google for their `site:domain.com` and parsing out the subdirectory string pattern in the returned URLs to create a list of subdomains. That should be doable with Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

`site:.example.com -www.example.com`

Comment: What do you expect to see when you search for this?   How does it help?

Comment: You get all indexed pages from subdomains except the www. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple!
All You need is to add an extra dot after "site:" and before "domain.com".
For Example, if you want to check index pages for "about.com"
you type "site:about.com" (without quotes) in Google.
,
But if you want to check the indexed subdomians of "about.com"
Simply type "site:.about.com" (without quotes).

Comment: Although this will return a list of various subdomains indexed, it doesn't answer the question of how to find out which subdomain is indexed _more_.

Comment: Well, It would be a 2 step process. First, follow the syntax I shared above then do what you normally do to check how many pages has been indexed for a site. Don't forget to add your desired subdomain. e.g. "site:subdomain.domain.com"

Comment: `then do what you normally do` <- that doesn't really answer anything, and you're just repeating what I indicated in the answer above.